# How can I get an arrow pointed on my border?

Tags: wpf, xaml, border, polygon

Ive tried a million things and im nearly there...

I have a border, and I want an arrow coming off to point upwards (I will do the same for each side and bottom after I have done this also). Here is what I have so far:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Polygon Points="5,0 10,10, 0,10" Stroke="Black" Fill="White" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,-2" Panel.ZIndex="10" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="1 0"  />
    <Border Background="#00000000" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" Grid.Row="1">
```

The polygon creates a perfect arrow, but the bottom border of the triangle is black and I want it white. Not sure how to get it to be white to look like the white BG bleeds into the arrow. Here is what it looks like so far:

[image]

I want to get rid of that black line underneath it. Am interested if there is a whole different approach I should be trying instead :)

Comment: you want that white just under the arrow, I meanwhere rectangle and arrow meets

Comment: Yes - I want it to look as though the border is 1 line, which points up like an arrow.

Comment: A new way for you: Microsoft expression blend. You can try with Path objects

Comment: Yeah, maybe creating a Path with a white triangle and a black line over it would be the better solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF/Silverlight: Is it possible to have a different stroke color for each edge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379307/wpf-silverlight-is-it-possible-to-have-a-different-stroke-color-for-each-edge)

Comment: please have a look the my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31724470/3873053

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit tricky. Wrap your triangle inside a `Grid` with `ClipToBounds` set to `true`. Then add another negative bottom `Margin` of -2 to that `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="10" ClipToBounds="True" Margin="0,0,0,-2">
        <Polygon Points="5,0 10,10, 0,10" Stroke="Black" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 Margin="0,0,0,-2" Panel.ZIndex="10" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="1 0"  />
    </Grid>
    <Border Background="#00000000" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" Grid.Row="1">
</Grid>
```

You may want to make your triangle bigger, since a slice of it will be hidden outside the `Grid`.

Comment: Now that I think of it, maybe the `Grid` will grow and not hide the triangle at all...

Comment: Edited with a slightly differet approach

Comment: The new approach worked great, thanks :) I applied the same thing to all other edges, using rendertransform to rotate them and modifying the margins etc :)

Answer (score 0):

Will this do?

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Background="#00000000" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,-2,0,0"/>
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Polygon Points="5,0 10,10, 0,10" Stroke="Black" Fill="White" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,0" Panel.ZIndex="10" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="1 0"  />
        <Polygon Points="1,10, 9,10" Stroke="White" Grid.Row="0"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Panel.ZIndex="10" StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="1 0"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Sits too high, needs to be brought down by margin -2 on bottom, which then makes this not work properly :(

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like that:

[image]

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="110*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="201*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <Grid>

            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Background="#00000000" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="10" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,-2,0,0"/>
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.75" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3.25" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="9" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="2" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Polygon Points="5,0 10,10, 0,10" Stroke="Black" Fill="White"  StrokeThickness="2" StrokeDashArray="1 0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" />

                    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                        <Rectangle Fill="White" Stroke="White" ></Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to make something like a Callout, so another option is to use an Adorner for the element inside the border. An Adorner allows you to draw some graphic related to that element. In this case may be a triangle.
Checkout [adorners overview on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(v=vs.85).aspx).

The code bellow is for an Adorner that could be applyed to a panel, and makes a callout.[image]

```
 protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        Rect adornedElementRect = new Rect(this.AdornedElement.DesiredSize);

        SolidColorBrush renderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);

        Pen renderPen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), 1);

        var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        var end = adornedElementRect.TopRight;

        stringBuilder.Append("M0,0");
        stringBuilder.Append(" L40,0 ");
        stringBuilder.Append(" 50,-10 ");
        stringBuilder.Append(" 60,0 ");
        stringBuilder.Append(end.X);
        stringBuilder.Append(",");
        stringBuilder.Append(end.Y);

        var stream = stringBuilder.ToString();

        drawingContext.DrawGeometry(renderBrush,renderPen, Geometry.Parse(stream));

    }
```